# How accurate is Find My Network for a turned off iPhone

Tags: iphone, network, bluetooth, find-my-iphone

I had my iPhone 11 stolen last week. The theft shut it down but I'm still able to localize it from time to time with Find My Network. It seems to be in an underground parking garage.

I was wondering how accurate Find My Network is **when the iPhone is turned off**.

Since the parking lot is on several floors, is it possible to have data on the altitude?

If you have any tips on how to find it, I would definitely be interested.

Comment: When the phone is powered off, if it is participating in Find My (Network), it is dependent on being bounced off other iPhones that are also participating in Find My (Network).  What you are getting is location data from the phone that received the ping.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. 

Unfortunately, I cannot make the phone ring since it's turned off. I am pretty sure it is on the underground garage because during week days, I received many more signals from the same place. 

Do you know how far can another phone be from the stolen one to receive a ping ? 

I have some high hopes to get it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is unknowable, as it depends on how well your phone and the phone or phones that "bounce" the signal can connect. A phone sitting on a car seat will connect better than one that's in the car's trunk. A closed trunk will interfere with radio wave signals too, how much will depend on the type of material (steel? aluminum? fiberglass?) used in the trunk lid. This will apply to all involved phones, and those phones' circumstances are unknown.

I assume there are a lot of parking spaces in the garage. Do you plan to stake out each occupied space and confront every driver, or follow every car that leaves the lot? With no more specific information, even an interested police department would have little to go on. Confronting the driver or following the car will expose you to personal risk.

With no disrespect, I would gently suggest that your hopes for recovery are misplaced.